# Array from plist file

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, dictionary

I have a plist file but a get disordered array from this file:

```
    if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "SomePlistFile", ofType: "plist"){

        if let array = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path){

          let list = Array(array.allKeys)
            print(list)

      }
    }
```

And result of print(list) is something look like this:

```
[9, 25, 18, 10, 26, 19, 11, 27, 12, 1, 28, 20, 13, 2, 29, 21, 14, 3, 4, 22, 15, 5, 6, 30, 23, 16, 7, 31, 24, 17, 8]
```

and I need array like `[1,2,3,....30,31]`

Comment: Use the `sorted()` something like  `let list = Array(array.keys).sorted()`

Comment: @ReinierMelian `sorted()` would not be available for `[Any]`, you should cast it to `[Int]` :) You could check my answer.

Comment: @AhmadF yes you are right but Another solution is casting the `NSDictionary` itself to `[Int:Any]`:) you could check my answer too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your question is a bit misleading. The result of `print(list)` cannot be an array of `Int` since all property list keys are required to be `String`.

Second of all, don't use the `NSDictionary` related API to read a property list from disk, use `Data` and `PropertyListSerialization` instead.

To sort the string keys numerically use `localizedStandardCompare`

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "SomePlistFile", withExtension: "plist")!
let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
let list = try! PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, format: nil) as! [String:Any]
let sortedList = list.keys.sorted{ $0.localizedStandardCompare($1) == .orderedAscending }
print(sortedList)
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting the `list` from the plist, as an array successfully, all you have to do for sorting it is to use [`sorted()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/2905744-sorted) array instance method.

However, since you are reading the values from a plist file, the type of `Array(array.allKeys)` would be `[Any]`, in order to be able to use the `sorted()` *you have to cast it*, like this:

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "SomePlistFile", ofType: "plist"){
    if let array = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path){
        if let list = Array(array.allKeys) as? [Int] {
            let sortedList = list.sorted()

            print(sortedList)
        }
    }
}
```

`sortedList` should be be as the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this is casting the `NSDictionary` to `[Int:Any]` this allow you call the `.sorted()`

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "SomePlistFile", ofType: "plist"){

        if let array = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as? [Int:Any]{

          let list = Array(array.keys).sorted()
          print(list)

      }
    }
```